# Databasing to feed ~9k data points to High Charts

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I am working on a freelance project that captures an audio file, runs some fourier analysis, and spits out three charts (x-y plots). Each chart has about ~3000 data points, which I plan to display with High Charts in the browser.

What database techniques do you recommend for storing and accessing this much data? Should I be storing the points in an array or in multiple rows? I'm considering Mongo too. Plan is to use Rails, so I was hoping to use a single database for both data and authentication.

I haven't dealt with queries accessing this much data for a single page, and this may very well be a tiny overall amount of data. In addition this is an MVP for demonstration to investors, so making it scalable to huge levels isn't of immediate concern.

My initial thought is that using Postgres and having one large table of data points, stored per-row, will be fine, and that that a bunch of doubles is not going to be too memory-intensive relative to images and such.

Realistically, I may just pull 100 evenly-spaced data points to make the chart, but the original data must still be stored.

Comment: Do you ever have to access any of these points individually, or you always access them as a group?

Answer (score 0):

I've done a lot of Mongo work and I can tell you what I would do if I were you.

One of the very nice properties about your data is that the x,y coordinates are of a fixed size generally. In other words it's not like you are storing comments from users, which can vary greatly in size.

With Mongo I would first make a sample document with the 3,000 points. Just a simple array of x,y points. I would see how big that document is and how my front end handled it - in other words can High Charts handle that?

I would also try to stick to the easiest conceptual model to manage, which is one document per chart, each chart having 3k points. This is a natural way to think of the data and I would start there and see if there were any performance hits. Mongo can easily store those documents, so I think the biggest pain would be in the UI with rendering the data.

Mongo would handle authentication well. I think it's a good choice for general data storage for an MVP.